# Has anyone Compared Qt Commercial Charts with matplotlib?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

What is better to use for interactive data plotting?
matplotlib (http://www.matplotlib.org) or Qt Commercial Charts (http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/Charts/) 
There are several functionality missing from matplotlib with regards to interactiveness like when I want to hover and display information specific related to the points in a scatter plots.
My overall program is in python and pyqt.
I also had a look at pyqtgraph.org but I dont think it is mature enough.

Comment: It is pretty easy to implement that hover capability.  There are a couple questions on SO showing how to do it.  See http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html for how to write call backs.

Answer (score 4):

`matplotlib` is interactive, see [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/interactive.html) - you can even embed it in [`Qt`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt.html) (which I use all the time and it works very very well).

You will find using `PyQt` for data plotting difficult for anything beyond simple plots. As far as I am aware, that "Qt Commercial Charts" thing you linked to isn't available in `PyQt` nor `pyside`, but you may want to take a look at [`PyQtGraph`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/).

But I would suggest that you stick with `matplotlib` first, and if it doesn't meet your needs then look elsewhere.